# VM is unreachable after vSphere HA Failover

Tags: vmware, high-availability, vsphere

I created a setup with a vCenter Sever 6.0 and and two ESXi 6.0 hosts. This is a PoC setup. I created a HA cluster and added hosts to it. Then I created a VM in one of the hosts and with a shared Datastore.

Now I disconnected the host where VM is running from the Network. I can see that the VM is relocated to the other running hosts after couple of minutes, but the VM become unreachable after relocation. I tried both DHCP based IP and static IP. Note that I have only one network with which the VMs are connected.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After the VM is registered to a different host, could you go to the VM properties and check that its using the correct Network Connection. Also check that the connected and connected at power on check boxes under Device Status are ticked.